# CompositionTarget.Rendering not always triggering on refresh

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've observed the following behavior with CompositionTarget.Rendering: if I don't do anything in the event handler, it is raised 30 times per second. If I invalidate something in the event handler, it is raised 60 times per second (discarding times when it is raised several times per frame).

My monitor's refresh rate is 60hz, so it looks like the event will skip a refresh if nothing was done last time it was raised.

What is the reason for this behavior and is there any way to get called consistently at the monitor's refresh rate without invalidating something every time?

This is on .NET 3.5 by the way.

Comment: Possbile duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812384/why-is-frame-rate-in-wpf-irregular-and-not-limited-to-monitor-refresh

Comment: @Fls'Zen I know about the fact that it can be called multiple times per frame and I'm already accounting for it.