# Is that possible to get GUI refresh times at WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, responsiveness

I really need to calculate responsiveness of my UI. Some suggested to use WpfPerf.exe (performance profiling tools for WPF). It works great however it does not have logging so it shows only last 1 minute of FPS as image.

However i need statistical information. The gui runs laggy so i need to record when exactly gui is refreshed. When there is no lag it should be refreshed each 0.5 seconds.

So i wonder anyhow i can record the time whenever gui is refreshed ?

.net 4.5.2 c# wpf

Comment: Add a [CompositionTarget.Rendering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx) handler.

Answer (score 1):

To record the time the GUI is refreshed. You may refer to 
[Why is Frame Rate in WPF Irregular and Not Limited To Monitor Refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812384/why-is-frame-rate-in-wpf-irregular-and-not-limited-to-monitor-refresh)

It may be out of topic. I would like to share what I do to improve my application last week.

- Use visual studio performance and diagnostic, if available, to find bottleneck.
- use BackgroundWorker to prepare data, instead of doing it in UI thread.
- use data virtulization for dispalying huge amount data, for example million rows. This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization) provides an excellent solution for displaying millon rows data smoothly.

Hope It will help.